# Migrate Google Play Developer account from indivual to business

Tags: android, playback

I currently have a Google Play Developer account as an individual. However I am starting my own company as a sole trader, so I need to move my payment profile from individual to business. Is there a way to do this without creating a new developer account and moving all my apps from one account to the other?

Comment: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6230247?hl=en have a look

Answer (score 4):

From the [Play Console Help](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10840893):

> ### Choosing an account type
>
> Google Play offers two developer account types: Personal and
> Organization. Personal and organization accounts have access to the
> same functionality and are able to monetize on Google Play using a
> payments profile; the only difference is the information we collect
> from you when you're setting up your account. ***You will be able to
> change your account type if your circumstances change.***